# MS Access 2007 report export does not work after installing AccessDeveloperExtensions.exe and AccessRuntime.exe

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime, ms-access-2007, developer-tools

In order to create an indipendent runtime `file.accdr` out of a `file.accdb`, I've downloaded `AccessDeveloperExtensions.exe` and `AccessRuntime.exe` and installed them.

Update:
[See article](https://www.pmi.it/tecnologia/software-e-web/tutorial/9769/distribuire-un-database-access-2007-senza-ms-office.html) Here is the [Google Translater](https://translate.google.it/?hl=it&sl=it&tl=en&op=translate) .
Update end.

Opening Access 2007 I could create the install package for creating the `file.accdr` out of the `file.accdb`.

The problem I get is that an important function does not work anymore. It's the export of a report, wherelse the export of a table still works.

Opening Access I get the [following message](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26193063/you-don%27t-have-a-source-code-control-program-such-as-Microsoft-Visual-Source-Safe-installed-on-your-machine-The-source-code-control-commands-are-therefore-not-available.html):

> you don't have a source code control program (such as Microsoft Visual Source Safe) installed on
> your machine. The source code control commands are therefore not available

I click on <kbd>OK</kbd> and Access opens my db.
My db is based on a table, a form, a report and a query. Exporting the report worked in the past, but doesn't work anymore. The message shown is the following:

> Impossible to complete output operation. Assure that there are no syntax errors. If the syntax is
> correct, reinstall Microsoft Office Accept...
>
> *(I've translated the text from Italian).*

Now is there another, easier way from reinstalling the hole thing? Because after reinstalling Access I will also have the need of creating `databases.accdr` and so I have reinstall `runtime.exe` and DeveloperExtensions again, what would result in the same problems I had before.

Somebody could help?

Comment: Huh? An accdr file is just an accdb file with the b at the end replaced by an r, to indicate it should behave like it was opened with the runtime version. Creating an accdr file is just: copy the file, rename to change the extension to an r. To work with accdr files, you don't need the runtime version, the full version can emulate the runtime version.

Comment: Yes, remove those installs (you may also need a System Restore), and run a renamed copy of the file. That's it.

Comment: @ErikA: Hmmm. I'm new in this sector. I've also tried to do what You wrote and it worked with a warning:"There is a potential security problem". When I click on Open, it opens anyway, wherelse file produced according the described procedure created the file that opens without this warning. But that was not my problem. I need that the function of Exportation of the Report runs again. Thanks.

Comment: @Gustav: Unfortunately I need them, because I need to produce a clean accdr, that doesn't produce any security issues.

Comment: But there is nothing to "produce". The developer extension is a tool for code versioning using the old Visual SourceSafe, the runtime is for users/machines not having Access installed. As for the security warning, this is a registry setting; refer to my article [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D).